Computing the language of an $S$-adic shift
I have been looking online for how or if one can compute the language of an $S$-adic subshift generated by finitely many substitutions. I know that one can compute the language of a substitution subshift. However, since I don't have a good grasp on $S$-adic subshifts whether one can compute their languages, as was answered by Dan Rust here. However, I am unsure of an analog in the $S$-adic setting for this sort of algorithm.
More concretely, say I want to compute all words/factors of length $k$ in the $S$-adic subshift. I assume that I have $\rho_1,...,\rho_r$ substitions on a single alphabet $A$ and that the subshift corresponds to a closed nonempty subset $S\subseteq\{ 1,...,r \}^{\mathbb{N}}$. I think I can assume that there exists an $\ell_k\in \mathbb{N}$
$$ 2k \leq \vert  \rho_{w_m}\circ ... \circ \rho_{w_{m+\ell_k-1}}(a) \vert $$
for all $a\in A$, all $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in S$ and all $m\in \mathbb{N}$. This is an assumption on a minimal growth rate.
I can then consider all $\ell_k$-strings appearing in $S$, and they correspond to a composition of $\ell_k$ many substitutions from $\{ \rho_1,...,\rho_r  \}$. I'll denote the obtained maps by $R_{\ell_k}(S)$. If I consider subwords $v$ occurring in $\phi(a)$ for some $\phi\in R_{\ell_k}(S)$, and then keep tracking $k$-words in $\phi'(v)$ for $\phi'\in R_{\ell_k}(S)$, will this give me a list of the $k$-words in the $S$-adic subshift?
I would appreciate any insights on this topic, as I don't think I understand the concept of a language of an $S$-adic subshift.

An S-adic subshift also has a directive sequence as a part of its definition. Unless you want to consider the union over all directive sequences? In any case, the desubstitution method is probably the easiest method. Start with a word and try desubstituting until you either can't any more of one of the branches of the tree of choices ends up at a single letter. Just remember that you now have to desubstitute according to the directive sequence (with respect to the last substitution first).

Of course, once you have some words already in your list, you can stop when you reach one of them instead of when reaching a single letter.
